# Fortran technical query

Tags: fortran

I have the following function signature in Fortran. I am new to the Fortran language - what is meant by `0.` in the function below?

```
ANTY(IAN,NA,0.,0.)
```

Answer (score 8):

The notation `0.` with a decimal point represents a floating point number, while `0` without a decimal point represents an integer. This is an important distinction for some implementations of FORTRAN, where the programmer must ensure that data types are consistent between the caller of a subroutine and the subroutine itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to `0.0` as a 32 bit real number (float in C)

Comment: It's only a default real, not necessarily 32-bit or interoperable with C's float (not that you say this latter part).  Beyond that, could you add more to this answer to distinguish it from the much older and more complete other answer?

Comment: That is only if you change the compiler interpretation of it. I rather use Real as 32 bit, and increase to 64 bit when necessary without changing the compiler flag.