# What is meant by . usage after a number in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

What is meant by . (dot) usage after a number in Fortran code?

For example:

```
x=a+b+45.-c-d
```

Comment: Wow, a fortran question!

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293265/fortran-technical-query

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: So why haven't you voted to close?

Answer (score 7):

This means that it's a floating point constant, not integer. **45.** is a shorter way to write **45.0**.