# What does DIST=AMAX1(0.,DI-DJ) means in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to understand a code in fortran language and i don't understand what does

DIST=AMAX1(0.,DI-DJ) means.

I am really confused with the dot(.) next to 0 .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
MAria

Comment: look at this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611802/what-is-meant-by-usage-after-a-number-in-fortran

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293265/fortran-technical-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AMAX1` is a function for obtaining the maximum value of two or more (single precision) floating point values. The `.` is there to indicate that the argument is a floating point value and not an integer. `0.` is short for `0.0`, FORTRAN allows you to omit the decimal zero.

There are lots of FORTRAN references on the Internet. [Here](http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/fortran/f77rm/6_intrinsics.doc.html) is a quick list of intrinsic functions, for example.

Comment: The list is quite obsolete for more than 20 years. Better one http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html  Also note that modern code should use just `max` (In FORTRAN 77 already!).

Comment: What Vladimir F is saying is that `AMAX1` is a specific function for arguments that are reals.  Instead you can use the generic `max` for arguments of any type and the compiler will figure out which of the specific functions to call, relieving the programmer of this task.